# Spring-AOP & MultiThreading

Tags: multithreading, spring-aop

i am having trouble multithreading my app. 
It seems AOP is unable to span over multiple threads i.e. 
i am unable to execute all the threads within a single transaction. 
Every thread updates the database on processing. 
I am using fixedThreadPool and ExecutorCompletionService. Is this a problem with spring?

Comment: I think you could clarify your question a bit because I have at least two way to interpret your question(s).

Comment: First one: You have an interceptor which you utilize the Thread classes in spring, but these wont thread out. The second: Is whether or not it's possible to have multiple threads in Spring which shares the same transactional context.

Comment: The second one sounds more closer to what's troubling me!

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution, but maybe it isn't the easiest setup, is to use JMS. You can send off multiple messages which are processed in parallel, and they can share the same transactional context.